# Trying to use Axios with Redux reducer... returns state is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

I am trying to use Axios with Redux reducer and trying to save response into state so that I can print it out, but when I try to prin the image to the page it returns typeError: state is undefined. I can console.log the response, but can't figure out how to save it or to get it working right.
[View picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1fvG.png)

```
import Axios from 'axios';
const initState = {
    some: '',
    cat: '',
}
const reducer = (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'GET_NEW_CAT':
        Axios.get('http://aws.random.cat/meow')
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data.file)
           return state.cat = response.data.file
        }) 
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
export default reducer;
```

Edit: This is where do the dispatching and mapping state:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CatsPage = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={props.getNewCatImage}>Get new cat image</button>
            <img src={props.cats} alt='Cat'/>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cats: state.cat
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        getNewCatImage: () => dispatch({type: 'GET_NEW_CAT'}),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CatsPage);
```

Comment: Given that error message, can you add the code for how your component is connected to state? In general pictures of code (or even errors) aren't helpful. Both code and error messages can be directly formatted into a question.

Comment: You are not returning anything in the case. In the reducer you should return each time the updated state. Also it would be better if you made your calls somewhere else eg. a saga, and left the reducer to just handle the changes of the state.

Comment: As @AlexG points out, and once again inspecting your error trace - note that log for the GET request happens after the error, which means you're reducer is returning undefined before receiving your async call. Usually, calls like that are made when the component is mounted or based on a button click. If you get a valid response back, then you would dispatch GET_NEW_CAT.

Answer (score 0):

What error say is that state is undefined. That means that your component is not connected to state apparently.

Sou you are missing a few steps here.

- Create a global reducer. Check [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)
- Use Provider from [react-redux](https://redux.js.org/basics/usagewithreact) to pass state in your app.

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, I do have Provider in my project and I am using connect to mapStateToProps and I believe that I do not need combineReducers at this point, since I am using only one reducer...And I do believe the problem lays in the Axios.get, when I try to set new value for 'cat', but I do not know what the problem is...

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating state with this line:

```
return state.cat = response.data.file
```

[When working with redux, state is immutable](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutabledata#why-is-immutability-required-by-redux) and thus you update state by using copies. Therefore you can use `Object.assign` as below:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, { cat: response.data.file })
```

Or more elegantly, the spread operator:

```
return { ...state, cat: response.data.file }
```

As an extra, the [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes) contains some recipes describing how to work with immutable state for various scenarios.

Comment: Hey, I am aware of that spread operator and changed my code back to it and even tried with object.assign, but error did not disappear. I just edited origanl post with details where I use mapStateToProps to get that state from reducer.